# Use LTW in Spring without -javaagent

Tags: spring, maven, aspectj

How can I use LTW in Spring without specifying -javaagent parameter in Vm arguments? I need the fields of beans from @Configurable classes to be injected, when they're created with "new" operator. Later I used maven-aspectj-plugin, but it doesn't support Java 1.8 yet (tell me if I am wrong), so I tried to use  with -javaagent and it worked. Now I want to avoid using -javaagent in VM arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with that library: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-instrument

Answer (score 1):

Well, just because Anton has answered this question after 4 years, let me add another answer: I think an additional library is not necessary. The AspectJ weaving agent can also be attached dynamically out of the box since I implemented it for AspectJ 1.8.7 (see [read-me file](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html)).

But maybe the other library (invesdwin-instrument) does something special related to Spring, I have no idea. Doing it with AspectJ directly works everywhere, also outside of Spring. AspectJ is not part of Spring but an external tool. I for example never use Spring, but pure AspectJ in other contexts.

---

**Update 2024-03-19:** If you are running your applications as **executable JARs on JRE 9+** (Spring Boot ones or other types), probably [Agent Embedder Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/agent-embedder-maven-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file) is what you want.

It enables you to embed a java agent in your executable JAR and have it started automatically using the [`Launcher-Agent-Class` JVM mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Unique features added by this plugin and unavailable via the original JVM mechanism: You can

- embed and run **multiple agents** (the JVM supports only one out of the box),
- pass an **option string** to each agent, just like from the JVM command line.

Spoiler: I am the author of the plugin and also happen to be the current maintainer of AspectJ.

P.S.: In the case of the AspectJ weaver, as the JVM starts the agent very early, weaving will be active without extra Spring configuration and it should work for all classloaders - no more `ClassLoader [...] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method` errors as seen when hot-attaching the weaver via `spring-instrument.jar`.